# streamlit only updates dataframe after every second change using st.data_editor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, artificial-intelligence, streamlit

I am trying to change the value in a column based on changes made by the user in a different column with st.data_editor, and want to do it live on change. But the following code only works after 2 changes and only shows the initial change.

code is run by running `streamlit run main.py`

### main.py

```
from page import page

page()
```

### page.py

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


boq_df = pd.DataFrame()


def update_dataframe():
    boq_df.loc[boq_df["ANALYZE"] == False, "TYPE"] = None
    boq_df.ffill(inplace=True)


def page():
    global boq_df

    st.write("# Test")

    if st.button("Analyze", type="primary"):
        boq_df = pd.DataFrame(
            data={
                "ANALYZE": [True, False, True],
                "CAT": ["Car", "Truck", "Bike"],
                "TYPE": ["blue", False, "yellow"],
                "DESC": ["two door", "four door", "single"],
            }
        )

    if not boq_df.empty:
        boq_df = st.data_editor(boq_df, height=700, on_change=update_dataframe())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a global variable in streamlit. Streamlit always rerun the code from top to bottom when there is a change in the user interface. Instead use the built-in dictionary-like session_state.

Also the `on_change` in the data editor is only useful when you add or delete a row. For editing, use the return value of the `data_editor` directly.

I tried to fix your code.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


# Create a session variable
if 'boq' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['boq'] = pd.DataFrame()


def page():
    st.write("# Test")

    # If button is pressed, assign a pre-built dataframe to the variable.
    if st.button("Analyze", type="primary"):
        st.session_state['boq'] = pd.DataFrame(
            data={
                "ANALYZE": [True, False, True],
                "CAT": ["Car", "Truck", "Bike"],
                "TYPE": ["blue", False, "yellow"],
                "DESC": ["two door", "four door", "single"],
            }
        )

    # If variable is not empty, construct a data_editor.
    if not st.session_state['boq'].empty:
        edited_df = st.data_editor(
            st.session_state['boq'],
            height=700
        )

        # If column "ANALYZE" is set to False, set the value of
        # "TYPE" to None. Be sure to update column "TYPE" only if
        # there are changes to column "ANALYZE".
        is_equal = edited_df['ANALYZE'].equals(st.session_state['boq']['ANALYZE'])
        if not is_equal:
            edited_df.loc[edited_df["ANALYZE"] == False, "TYPE"] = None
            edited_df.ffill(inplace=True)
            st.session_state['boq'] = edited_df  # update the variable

            # Set streamlit to rerun the script from top to bottom
            # to update the data editor.
            st.rerun()

page()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, and it's what I need, but is there a way to just reload the dataframe without reloading the entire script?

Comment: No. It is the prime directive of streamlit to rerun the code from top to bottom whenever there are changes in the states. In doing so, they might have sidestepped a multitude of bugs in the framework as they progressed, thereby facilitating the implementation of features without any difficulties.